# custom error Response for volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a `Stringrequest` in Android Studio and it's working correctly, I mean I get the response on `onResponse` method, now I want volley to return an error when the error key has true value. how can i do it?

this is my request:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_OTP_REQUEST,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("response", response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        startVerificationActivity(jsonObject.get("sender").toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("error", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("mobilePhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);

            return params;
    };
```

this is the answer of the server:

`{"sender":"10008727","error":true}`

all I want is to set volley to run `onErrorResponse` when `error` is `true` in the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new custom `AppStringRequest` class which inherits from `StringRequest` and handle the above usecase.

```
public class AppStringRequest extends StringRequest {

    // ... constructor ...

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        // You will receive your response here in the response parameter.
        // parse the response and check whether the response has "error":true
        String parsed;
        try {
            parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            parsed = new String(response.data);
        }

        // if it's an error, return Response.error(), otherwise, return Response.success()

        try {
            JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(parsed);
            boolean error = resObj.getBoolean("error");
            if (error) {
                return Response.error(new VolleyError());
            } else {
                return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStractTrace()
              // your server response has some issues
        }
        return Response.error(new VolleyError("Error message")); // can send error message in the VolleyError
    }        

}
```

Then you have to use this `AppStringRequest` instead of the default `StringRequest`.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new AppStringRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_OTP_REQUEST,
            ... )
```

The error message will be available in the `onErrorResponse`:

```
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("Volley error", error.toString()); //the error message
   }
```